# validation check on 3 fields to check duplication

Tags: php, sql

i am new to php but trying to learn new things. i have a table in database with three fields. id, city and name. what i want is to check if all these three fields are equal by getting value from text box, then it show error else it would show me a link to redirect to a new page. but i am not able to run this query properly tried several things like count etc.

```
<form>
<input id="text1" type="text" name="id" size="20" > 
<input id="text1" type="text" name="name" size="20" > 
<input id="text1" type="text" name="city" size="20" > 
<input id="text1" type="submit" name="submit" size="20" > 
</form>

<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","test");
$check="SELECT * FROM eval WHERE id = '$_POST[id]' AND name = '$_POST[name]'  AND city = '$_POST[city]' ";

if( if all this data is same then ) {
echo "Record already exist...<br/>";
}
else
{
echo "<a href='NewUser.php'> New Sign Up </a>
}
?>
```

Comment: any idea would be appreciated to get the required result, query could be any thing but need to check all these three field before routing user to next page ...

Answer (score 1):

```
<form>
    <input id="text1" type="text" name="id" size="20" >
    <input id="text1" type="text" name="name" size="20" >
    <input id="text1" type="text" name="city" size="20" >
    <input id="text1" type="submit" name="submit" size="20" >
</form>

<?php
    $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","test");
    $check="SELECT COUNT(*) FROM eval WHERE id = '$_POST[id]' AND name =  '$_POST[name]'  AND city = '$_POST[city]' ";
    $result = mysqli_query($con,$check);
    $count = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
    if(current($count) > 0) {
        echo "Record already exist...<br/>";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "<a href='NewUser.php'> New Sign Up </a>
    }
?>
```

You have to fire the `SQL` Query to the database using `mysqli_query()`. Afterwards your checking if count of the rows is bigger than 0, which means you found 1 or more exact duplicated rows.

`SELECT COUNT(*)` Automatically counts the retrieved rows.

Comment: Not working ... on page load this query is showing me else statement ... can you please check ... i want to run this on submit button to check the validation

Comment: @A1Nasir Of course it does. Wrap it into a `if(isset($_POST['submit'])) { }` or something like that...

Answer (score 1):

Okay so you have a HTML form and some PHP code that is to handle what happens when the form is submitted.

So, when the form is submitted then in order for PHP to register this submission is needs to know that the form was submitted.

You have a form that might work well on the client side if you were processing the form input via JavaScript but in PHP it is a little different.

So your form would need two additional things:

1.) A method attribute which specifies how the form data will be sent.

2.) An action defining where the form data will be sent to.

The most common methods would be GET and POST. And as you have the PHP code the handles the form on the same page as the form, the action will be the page itsself. So you have now:

```
<form method="POST" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
  <input type="text" name="id">
  <input type="text" name="name">
  <input type="text" name="city">
  <input type="submit" name="clicked" value="formSubmit">
</form>
```

In PHP in order for you to register this input, you can use the event that occurs when the Submit button has been clicked. So you will have:

```
<?php
  # If the submit button was clicked
  if (isset($_POST['clicked']) && $_POST['clicked'] == 'formSubmit') {
    # Access the form inputs in php
    $id = $_POST['id'];
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $city = $_POST['city'];

    # Helper to output mysql errors
    function processError($link)  {
      echo "Error: Unable to connect to MySQL.<br>";
      echo "Debugging errno: " . $link->errno . "<br>";
      echo "Debugging error: " . $link->error . "<br>";
      exit;
    }

    # Connect to the database
    // Create a database connection for PHP to use
    $link = mysqli_connect($DBHost, $DBUser, $DBPass, $DBName);
    // Ensure the connection is active
    if (!$link) {
      echo "Error: Unable to connect to MySQL.<br>";
      echo "Debugging errno: " . mysqli_connect_errno() . "<br>";
      echo "Debugging error: " . mysqli_connect_error() . "<br>";
      exit;
    }
    // Sets encoding type to uft8
    if (!mysqli_set_charset($link, 'utf8')) { processError($link); }

    # Do query
    // Build query
    $query = 'SELECT `id` ';
    $query .= 'FROM `eval` ';
    $query .= 'WHERE `id` = ? ';
    $query .= 'AND `name` = ? ';
    $query .= 'AND `city` = ? ';
    $query .= 'LIMIT 1 ';
    // Prepare the statement
    if (!$stmt = $link->prepare($query)) { processError($link); }
    // Bind in form values to prevent sql injection
    if (!$stmt->bind_param('iss', $id, $name, $city)) { processError($link); }
    // Execute the query
    if (!$stmt->execute()) { processError($link); }
    // Store the result
    $stmt->store_result();
    // Store the number of rows returned
    $num_rows = $stmt->num_rows;
    // Close the statement
    $stmt->close();

    # Check if the record exists
    if ($num_rows == 1) {
      echo 'Record already exist...<br/>';
    }
    // No record exists
    else {
      echo '<a href="NewUser.php"> New Sign Up </a>';
    }
  }
?>
```

Hope that helps you :-)